# Android SDK SharedPreferences troubles

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, sharedpreferences

I'm working on an app and would like to save the state of obe of my checkbox options, but when I try using the SharedPreferences class (first time using it) I get a nullpointer exception. I have been troubleshooting for a couple hours and cant find a solution. Could anyone look at this and tell me what's wrong? The full code is alot longer but this is the park giving me the null pointer exception. I know for a fact it has to do with SharedPreferences.

```
package us.mattmccoy.meanfind;

//import java.util.Arrays;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.ClipData;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


//saved data stuff needed
SharedPreferences preferences = this.getSharedPreferences("us.mattmccoy.meanfind", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 
Editor edit = preferences.edit();
//private data using saved data
String autoclearKEY = "us.mattmccoy.meanfind.AUTOCLEAR";
boolean autoclear = preferences.getBoolean(autoclearKEY, false);

//normal private data
final Context con1 = this;
int dividend;String dataFixed;boolean tb;
private CheckBox myCBox, acBox;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    addListenerBoxes();
    if(autoclear == true){
        acBox.setChecked(true);
    }else{
        acBox.setChecked(false);
    }
}
//check box listeners
public void addListenerBoxes(){
    //instantiate boxes
    acBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chex2);
    acBox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
                    //is acBox checked?
            if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
                edit.putBoolean(autoclearKEY, true).commit();
            }else{
                edit.putBoolean(autoclearKEY, false).commit();
            }
          }
    });
    myCBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chex);

}
```

error message:

http://pastebin.com/5P2Mfwik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line

```
SharedPreferences preferences = this.getSharedPreferences("us.mattmccoy.meanfind", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

to

```
SharedPreferences preferences; = this.getSharedPreferences("us.mattmccoy.meanfind", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

and put

```
preferences = this.getSharedPreferences("us.mattmccoy.meanfind", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

in `onCreate()`

You are trying to use `Context` before establishing it with `onCreate()` so you are getting `NPE` on `context`. You will also want to move these lines

```
Editor edit = preferences.edit();
boolean autoclear = preferences.getBoolean(autoclearKEY, false);
```

into `onCreate()` after you initialize `preferences` or you will get another `NPE` since `preferences` will be `null` until you initialize it. So it should be something like

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
//saved data stuff needed
SharedPreferences preferences;   //declare them
Editor edit;
//private data using saved data
String autoclearKEY = "us.mattmccoy.meanfind.AUTOCLEAR";
boolean autoclear;
        @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    SharedPreferences preferences; = this.getSharedPreferences("us.mattmccoy.meanfind",   Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Editor edit = preferences.edit();   //initialize them
    boolean autoclear = preferences.getBoolean(autoclearKEY, false);
    addListenerBoxes();
    if(autoclear == true){
        acBox.setChecked(true);
    }else{
        acBox.setChecked(false);
    }
```

If this doesn't solve your problem then please post full logcat

Comment: Did you see my updated answer? Please post full logcat if you are still getting an error

Comment: when I move Editor object edit into onCreate() other methods in my class can't access it. Why is that/how do I circumvent it?

Comment: You can declare it as a member variable (before `onCreate()` `Editor edit;` But you can't initialize it until after you initialize your `preferences` in `onCreate()`

Comment: I have made another edit that may make it more clear. Also, you don't need, `final Context con1 = this;` as far as I can tell. If you are in an `Activity` method you can just use `this` if not you can use `MainActivity.this`

Comment: I accidentally crashed my emulator but it looks like this works! Does this save the preference even after the app closes? EDIT: yeah the con1 was leftover code I needed to clean up.

Comment: Yes, `SharedPrefs` are persistent

Comment: don't forget to call `commit()` on your `Editor` when you are done with it

Comment: Yeah it was a big help. Only other problem i'm getting is an error about one of my activities not having a parent activity defined, even though it does. (it works too) So I don't know what's up with that.

Comment: nevermind; it looks like fixing the SharedPreferences error fixed the other one too!

Comment: Good! Note my comment about calling `commit()` if you aren't already doing so then click the little checkmark next to the answer so it may help others